# How do I adjust similar photos to match? (automatic image registration task)

Tags: image-processing, centering, image-scaling, autorotate, edge-detection

I have a set of weight loss progress photos of myself that are all very similar, with a white, empty background. I would like to have a base photo and a script(s) (of any kind) that will correct the minor variations (angle, color(white-balance), distance) betweens shots without manual intervention, so that shoulders, hips and cropping match up when flipping though photos.

Requirements (all in respect to a base image I create):
Non-distorting
Match shoulder width (resizing)
rotation adjustment
white-balance
cropping (rough is alright) (if I only go down the knees in the base image other images should remove calves or head, etc.)

I'm so uninformed in this area I'm not sure what I should be looking for (so a simple google search might be all I need).

What are the tools that I should look at? C, C++, Python, MatLab, Shell are all fine for libs/tools.

UPDATE:
Doing more research I've found that this is called automatic image registration.

Comment: I don't think that you'll be able to find something that just does this. You may be able to find something that would do what you want with some modifications, but my guess is you'd have to write the modification algorithms yourself.

Comment: This is called automatic image registration and should take little work on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a basic tutorial on how to do this in Python using OpenCV in python.

http://www.neuroforge.co.uk/index.php/image-registration

This is only a partial answer though.